# Finding a non zero vector in the column space

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let the matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix}-12&-12&16&-15\\-6&-8&8&-10\\0&20&0&25\end{bmatrix}$
>
> Find a non zero vector in the column space of $M$

Is it not true that $\begin{bmatrix}-12\\-8\\20\end{bmatrix}$ is a non zero vector in the column space of $M$ ? For some reason it keeps telling me "***that is incorrect your answer doesn't seem to be a Vector***". I'm typing in -12 -8 20, then I tried [-12,-8,20] then i tried {-12, -8, 20}

Comment: That should be in the column space. We won't be able to tell you much about what format your school's sit expects, but have you tried (-12,-8,20)?

Comment: Yes that was incorrect to

Comment: I think it has got to do with how you have to enter vector notation. The entries seem to be fine. You need to figure out the formatting. not much we can do here at this point, I am afraid